# What is the decimal representation of the 10-adic 1 000...000?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

What is the decimal representation of the 10-adic 1 000...000?

The space character is for clarity only.

Comment: What do you mean by $1000\dots000$?

Comment: The 10-adic number that starts with the digit 1, and then to it'a right has a countably infinite number of 0 digits.

Comment: The table with fractions? Or with binary values?

Comment: See the table at the bottom of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Introduction. The table with fractions.

Comment: Ok, I misread it, still curious but thanks guys :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decimals of the $10$-adic numbers go potentially infinite long *on the left*, for example, we have $\dots 999999999=-1$.

There is no such thing that a digit *before* the countably infinte digits... The remaining $1$ keeps being thrown on the left when processing $\dots 999999+\dots 000001$, and eventually *it will be lost* at the end.

A $p$-adic number has an $n$th digit for each *natural number* $n$, and is fully determined by these digits, but this $n$ itself can't be infinty. Actually, dropping the remainder at the edge of infinity is a basic feature of $p$-adics..

Comment: See the table at the bottom of en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Introduction, for example 6/7ths.

Comment: Well, $6/7=\dots\,714285\,714285\,714285\,8$  as $10$-adic number, according to the table. Your number wants to be $1+\overline 9$, no? But that counts the same as $0$ among $10$-adic numbers.

Comment: What's exactly your question now? $2/3=\dots 333334$. Start to multiply this number by $3$ on a paper, from the right, and carry on the remaining $1$. You will get $\dots 0000002$, which is just $2$.

Comment: Well, having a finite (moreover negative fraction) value for $1+10+100+1000+10000+\dots$ can also be intuitively confusing..

Comment: I understand your answer properly now. Thanks :)